# Приложение-чат для локальной сети

Tags: python, сеть, сокет

**Задача:** написать приложение обмена сообщениями между несколькими компьютерами локальной сети.

**Инструментальные средства:** Python 3.6

Только начинаю разбираться с сетевым программированием и сокетами, каша в голове. На данный момент единственный принцип сетевого программирования, который я усвоил это:

1. Создается сокет на сервере и ожидает приема клиентских запросов
2. Создается сокет на клиенте и оправляется на сервер
3. Клиент получает ответ от сервера

Не могу понять, как можно решить поставленную задачу. Что может являться сервером в локальной сети при обмене сообщениями между узлами? Или можно ли как-то реализовать это без сервера? Дайте какое-нибудь наставление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация без сервер на прямую никак не связана с работой с сокетами и только сильнее запутает при обучении. Потому постараюсь объяснить в чем суть при работе с сервером. 
Давайте немного уточним основные принципы.

Запускается приложение которое создает сокет. 
*Сокет* определяют два значения: *хост* и *порт*.

**Хост** - значение которое говорит соединения с каких интерфейсов нужно слушать (интерфейс грубо говоря сетевое устройство).Например значение **127.0.0.1** говорить что нужно слушать на интерфейсе **loopback**, который зациклен сам на себя и доступен только самому устройству, компьютеры присоединение к локальной сети к нему не достучатся, или **0.0.0.0** значение которое говорит что можно принимать соединение с любого интерфейса, к такому приложению можно достучатся с самого устройства, с компьютеров в локальной сети и даже из глобальной сети(если проведены соответствующие настройки), ну или IP-адрес внутри локальной сети (что-то в духе **192.168.0.10**), что позволит доступ только из компьютеров из локальной сети.

**Порт** - идентификатор который определяет само приложение(а также, довольно часто, протокол необходимый для общения, 80 - http, 443 - https, 25 - smtp и т.д.). Порты с 0 по 1023 желательно не использовать, так как часто у них есть какое-то общеизвестное применение и возможны конфликты. 49152—65535 чаще всего используются для короткоживущих соединений, о них упомяну немного позже. Ну а те которые остались по сути свободны для общего использования.

Создается сокет на клиенте и питается установить соединение с сервером.

Очень важно понимать что клиент также создает сокет который тоже описывается хостом и портом. Где хост будет IP-адресом в подсети через интерфейс которой будет установлено соединение, а порт - случайно сгенерирован из диапазона 49152—65535.

После чего на сервере будет создано **соединение** которое описывается уже 4 значениями **хост_сервера**:**порт_сервера**-**хост-клиента**:**порт_клиента**
(ну и файловым дескриптором, но это сейчас не важно)
Оно и определяет от кого именно пришел запрос и кому отправить ответ. Такое устройство позволяет общаться сразу  с несколькими клиентами.

А теперь немного о том как это должно выглядеть. Условимся что HOST - IP-адрес устройства в подсети, PORT - порт из допустимого диапазона.

Есть центральное приложение - сервер. Оно запущено на одном из устройств в локальной сети. Слушает на **0.0.0.0:PORT** или **HOST:PORT**. К нему можно получить доступ с самого устройства и из других устройств в локальной сети стучась только на **HOST:PORT**.

Comment: Т.е. пользователь с одного компьютера создает чат-комнату (становясь сервером), а другие компьютеры к нему могут подключаться. Я правильно понял? Если да, то получается, что когда хозяину комнаты надоест общаться и он выйдет, чат прервется для всех собеседников, верно?

Comment: Нет, немного не так. Имеется ввиду что сервер это отдельное приложение которое должно бить запущено на одном из устройств, оно работает в независимости от того подключен к нему кто-то или нет. Главное чтоб оно работало и недоступным оно станет только если кто-то специально остановит приложение. Как результат, это лучше чем чат-комната инициализированная отдельным пользователем, но прекращающая свое существование после его отключения, но и не так хорошо как решение с внешним постоянно включенным сервером, так как необходимо одно постоянно включенное устройство внутри сети.